# How to use single responsibility with functions

Tags: c, software-design, code-cleanup

I've just read the book called clean code. The author Uncle Bob talks about a single responsibility that a function should have in a program. It should only do one thing.

Now, I would like to understand how is it now possible to reuse a code that does multiple things. Let's say I have a method called `runTrafficAndCheckIfItPassed` and it calls two methods inside of it: `runTraffic` and `checkIfTrafficPassed`.

Now let's say that in my software I need to run traffic and to check it's result in a lot of places in my software. sometimes i need to check that traffic has failed, and sometimes i need to check if it passed.

Why wouldn't it be right to call the `runTrafficAndCheckIfItPassed` function and why is it way better to call the functions inside separately?

As far as I see, if there will be a change in the `runTraffic` function, for example to receive another  parameter, the change will be implemented in one place, only in `runTrafficAndCheckIfItPassed`, which we see will be kinda easy to maintain.
But if i will use the functions seperately i will need to change it in any place.
But Bob says it's wrong? Got any examples or tips why it is called wrong?

Comment: If everywhere you call `RegisterAuser` you also call `ValidatedThatAuserisRegistered` then it really isn't two things, is it?

Comment: I edited again, and it does two things.

Comment: [softwareengineering.se] is a better place to ask questions about software design principles.

Comment: alright ill check there too, thank you.